# How can get page content which app using AngularJS with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, capybara

I want to get such URL with Capybara:

```
visit '/user/#/works'
```

I can get menu only. I can't get the other content generated by AngularJS.

How to get it?

Comment: you can scroll the related part of the single page application instead of going it directly

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: @TomWalpole Selenium